# Why is big O notation an asymptotic notation/analysis?

Tags: big-o, algorithm-analysis

An asymptote in mathematics represents a value (line) to which the observed function constantly approaches. In other words, as the value of X increases towards infinity, i.e. decreases towards minus infinity, the value of the function approaches that value/line (asymptote).

When we talk about the big O notation, such a value/line (asymptote) that the function (description of the algorithm) approaches does not exist, so I wonder **why the big O notation is defined as the asymptotic analysis of the algorithm? What does asymptotic mean in the context of algorithmic analysis? I know that the big O notation represent upper bound of the function that represents algorithm, so does that upper bound has something with the asymptote?**

Comment: Why do you say that such asymptote does not exist for the analysed function?

Comment: @Bergi For example, if we have functions f(x)=2x^2+20x and g(x)=4x^3. g(x) is not an asymptote to the function f(x), but it is an upper bound.

Comment: Ah well to find the asymptote itself, try Θ (big Theta) notation instead… But even if 4x^3 is not the asymptote in your example, that's not the same as saying no asymptote exists.

Comment: @Bergi It seems that indeed g(x) is not an asymptote for f(x). See Doc Brown's answer below. He explained it very well.

Comment: @Bergi: any suggestion of what the asymptote of ` f(x)=2x^2+20x` might be? Hint:  `g(x)=2x^2` would be wrong, since  |f(x)-g(x)| is not converging to zero.

Comment: @joke If you have two functions f(x)=2x^2+20x and g(x)=4x^3, then g is **not** an upperbound of f; as a counterexample, f(1) > g(1), so you cannot say that f < g. However, g is an **asymptotical upperbound** of f, because *in the neighbourhood of infinity*, f < g, i.e. there exists a constant M such that when restricted to the interval [M, +oo), f < g.

Comment: @Stef Yes, thanks Stef. I meant asymptotical upper bound, I left out the word asymptotical somehow.

Comment: @DocBrown if you don't restrict it to linear asymptotes, you can find any number of curves that fulfill this requirement. `f` is trivially an asymptote to itself, `g(x) = 2x²+20x+x⁻¹` is another. (Not saying that these are useful, just that they exist). Of course, in algorithmic analysis `f` is typically more complicated, with lots of smaller components in a finite region. Consider `f(x) = max(100, 2x²+floor(20x))` - `g(x) = 2x²+20x` is a *useful* asymptote to that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, ἀσύμπτωτος merely means "not falling together". Which would suggest that a function is not asymptotic to itself!? Sometimes, etymology raises more questions than it answers ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> An asymptote in mathematics represents a value (line) to which the observed function constantly approaches.

Well, that is a narrow definition of the term asymptote. A more general definition allows also **non-linear** curves as asymptotes. The [english Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) currently leaves this point-of-view out, but other sources [like the german Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Nichtgerade_Asymptoten) mention them.

This is, however, not the full story, since in context of big-O, `f(x) = O(g(x))` does not mean  `g(x)` being asymptote an for `f(x)`. To express the difference, in computer science, we usually say that `g(x)` is an "asymptotic upper bound" for `f(x)`. Formally, this means

```
lim sup  |(f(x)/g(x))|  = c    for some non-negative real value c < ∞
  x->∞
```

Hence, the value c ( or line "y=c") is indeed an asymptote for `|(f(x)/g(x))|` ( to be precise: for `h(x)= sup{|(f(t)/g(t))| : t > x}`. This is sometimes confused with `g(x)` ( or `c * g(x)`) being an asymptote for `f(x)`, which is mathematically not correct.

So yes, the usage of the term "asymptotic" in computational complexity may not be exactly the same as in other mathematical fields, but it is clearly related and can be interpreted in a way it points back to it's origin, using strict mathematical definitions.

Comment: Hey Doc Brown, amazing (amazing!!!) answer, but I have a couple of questions. First of all, can you see the comment I left on Jörg's question. What do you mean about that? Second, what do you mean by saying asymptotic upper bound? If I understood correctly, g(x) is not an asymptote for the f(x). Also f(x)/g(x) => c*g(x) is not an asymptote for the f(x). c is just an asymptote for the f(x)/g(x) and by g(x) we limit f(x) to grows. Third, you said that c must be > 0. But what in the case f(x)=x^2+40x; g(x)=x^3. In this case c=0, so by the formula it is not an upper bound, but as I know it is?

Comment: @joke: c is  an asymptote for `|f(x)/g(x)|` (absolute value!). And you are right, c can be zero, for "big-O", see my edit. The term "asymptotic upper bound" is just the term CS people use for this, see my other edit.

Comment: @joke: ... and to Jörg's answer and your comment: I would not go so far and say *"asymptotic in CS has nothing to do with the term's definition in analytical geometry (or mathematics at all)"*. It may not be exactly the same, but can still be defined using mathematical terms.

Comment: Thanks Doc a lot, really. Can you just tell me one more thing. So for the f(x) = 2x^2+10x; g(x)=x^2, c is 2. This is the asymptote for the |f(x)/g(x)|. But by the definition of big O, we say f(x)=O(g(x)) as x->inf if there exist **some constants c**, x0 such that |f(x)| < c|g(x)| for all x > x0. I don't understand how can it be `some constant`, i.e. any constant which meets the conditions, shouldn't it be exactly 2? How can it be any, when it doesn't match mathematically (at least I think it doesn't).

Comment: @joke: when using the  `|f(x)| < c|g(x)| ... ` definition (instead of the lim sup definition) for big-O, choosing c=2 would be wrong, since 2x^2+10x is never smaller than 2x^2 for all x >0. But when you pick c = 2.001, or c=2 + ε, where ε is some value >0, then the condition will hold for all x beyond som x0.

Comment: @joke it holds for `c=3`, `c=4`... etc. There's an infinity of values that it does hold for, from which you only need one. There's a preference to state the *smallest*, but that ends up dealing with infinitesimals

Comment: Hey Doc, I'd like to thank you again for the phenomenal answer you gave. I gave myself a few days to think better about what you wrote, so I didn't answer anything or accept your answer yet (which I want to do now). However, I would just like to see if I understood everything correctly. In the following, there is a little more text with which I tried to explain the connection between bio O notation and asymptotes. It would mean a lot to me if you read it and tell me if I didn't understand something well. It's against the rules of the site, but I can delete it later. **Thank you very much.**

Comment: Big O is a mathematical notation used to describe the "limiting behavior" of a function as its argument (x) tends to some value or +inf. In other words, f(x) is big O of g(x) if g(x) represents the upper limit/bound beyond which f(x) cannot go. For example, for the function `f(x)=2*x^2+10x`, the functions `g(x)=2*x^2+10x+1` and `j(x)=4*x^3+20x+2` represent the given limit/bound, but also the function f(x) represents a limit/bound to itself in some way because it cannot go beyond itself. If we only looked at things this way, then the Big O notation would actually only denote the upper bound.

Comment: However, Big O is far more powerful than that. Big O enables the limit/bound of complex functions to be presented through simple functions that are not actually their upper bound (not a real limit/bound), but represent a **limit/bound in the context that they are the most important factor in the growth of the function and describe what limits a certain function to go faster**. It's called asymptotic upper bound, not an upper bound. So, the term `bound` in this case have a different meaning.

Comment: For example, `f(x)=2x^2+20x+4` is O(x^2), because for a large x, `20x+4` is not what limits/bounds the growth of the function, it is `2x^2`. Additionally, 2 can be ignored, because it actually just scales the bound by a certain constant (in this case 2). Of course, this must be mathematically supported and accurate. That is why we calculate |f(x)/g(x)|. If this is `< 1` for all values as x goes to +inf, we would have an upper bound. However, in the context of Big O notation, bound has different meaning and it is only important that it goes towards some non-zero value as x goes to infinity.

Comment: Here, there may be slight deviations for some functions at the beginning, but then everything will be fine. For example, for the functions `f(x)=2*x^2-20x+4`, `g(x)=x^2`, as x goes to +inf the results are in order (8.0;3.0;1.33;0.5;0 and then moves toward 2). That value towards which it is going actually represents a constant in front of the strongest term if basic functions like `n^2` are used for g(x). That value actually also represents the asymptote of f(x)/g(x). That is why it is said that g(x) is the asymptotic upper bound for f(x) and not the "real" upper bound or asymptote of the f(x).

Comment: The fact that f(x)/g(x) goes towards some value (let's say 2 in the example) and constantly approaches it means that `n^2` in relation to other elements of the function (`-20x+4`), when we divide them, constantly reduces their influence as x goes to +inf. This is precisely why n^2 represents this "new defined" (asymptotic) upper bound (not the literal/real one) of the function `f(x)=2x^2-20x+4`. At the end, we can also represent it in the opposite direction and without `lim` and just say that `g(x) is an asymptotic upper bound of f(x) if f(x)<c g(x) as x->+inf for some c and x>x0`.

Comment: @joke All correct, except this: *"That is why we calculate |f(x)/g(x)|. If this is < 1 for all values as x goes to +inf, we would have an upper bound. However, in the context of Big O notation, bound has different meaning and it is only important that it goes towards some non-zero value as x goes to infinity."* The quotient `|f/g|` doesn't have to "go towards some non-zero value", it only has to "become bounded" ie at some point it stays below some constant value. (And if f is a function of integers only, then "become bounded" and "is bounded" are equivalent)

Comment: @joke: Stef is right. For example, think of a function like this: f(x)=2*x^2-20x+4 when x is an even integer, f(x)=0 for each odd integer. Still f would be O(x^2).  I added a small clarification to my answer.

Comment: @Stef So If I got it right, the problem is "go towards some non-zero value" since it does not need to go towards some value as x goes to +inf. For example, for the functions `f(x)=2x^2+10x`, `g(x)=x^2` this will be true,  since `|f(x)/g(x)|` **always goes towards 2** (...2.025, 2.024...2.001975, 2.00193... to 2). Also correct for the functions `f(x)=2x^2-10x`, `g(x)=x^2`, with the starting deviation where until `x=5` it goes to zero, but then it goes towards 2 from the "down side" (...1.965,1.1968...1.9935,19937... to 2). However, this is not always true.

Comment: @Stef For example, for the function `f(n)=10+sin(n)` most dominant term is 10, so `g(x)=1`. However, we can't find an asymptote, that is the value to which `f(x)/g(x)` approaches as x goes to inf since asymptote (lim) does not exist in this case. In this case `f(x)/g(x)` **does not goes towards some values** but oscillates between 9 and 11 as x goes to +inf. However, even if lim does not exist, big O still does and its O(1). **For this case it's questionable whether we can then call it asymptote upper bound?**

Comment: @Stef As conclusion, it is true that in CS it will in most cases go towards some value (asymptote), but in general it is not always true. So, it is more accurate to say that, as you said, `at some point it stays below some constant value`. However, is this tottally accurate since for the above mentioned functions `f(x)=2x^2+10x`, `g(x)=x^2`, it does stay below 2 (it goes towards 2 from the upper side). Is everything okay now?

Comment: Hey Doc, I read your edit. Not sure If I understood correctly, but it looks like what I wrote to Stef. What do think about it? Also not sure if I understood this: `f(x)=2*x^2-20x+4 when x is an even integer, f(x)=0 for each odd integer.` For example, for x=13, f(x) is no 0 but 16,128.

Comment: @joke: these comment sections are not suited well for such an extended discussion. But FWIW, f(n)=10+sin(n) is clearly O(1), and g(x)=1 is an asymptotic upper bound for this function, that's correct. I don't think, however, that *"in CS it will in most cases go towards some value"*. Maybe "most cases you personally have seen in some books".

Comment: I understand that f(n)=10+sin(n) is O(1) but how can g(x)=1 be the "real" asymptotic  upper bound when lim(x->inf) |f(x)/g(x)| does not exist in this case?

Comment: @joke: `lim sup |f(x)/g(x)|` (with x->inf) exists - it is 11. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about the sup. **Thank you very much!** So it's an asymptotic upper bound and it's not true that in CS it goes towards some values in most cases. What do you think of the rest? I mean that's what Stef and you tried to point out to me? That it is not always necessary to go to some value as X goes to inf, but there are also frequent cases like 10+sin(x) where there is no approaching to some value?

Comment: @joke: how do you count the "frequency of cases in CS"? I guess can invent as many cases for functions and sequences which converge somewhere as I can invent functions or sequences which don't. When does a case count "as a case from CS"? When there is a real world use case where this function occurs? When there is some hypothetical case from theoretical CS? Honestly, I am not sure what you want to ask me.

Comment: I didn't express myself well. First I said that in most cases it goes toward some value, where you corrected me and said that it is not quite like that (as you said `Maybe "most cases you personally have seen in some books".`). So then I gave one example (`10+sin(x)`) where it is not a case of going towards some value, but oscillations. My question is, is that what you and Stef meant? That there are also such cases, and not only those where f/g goes toward some value as x goes to inf+?

Comment: @joke: well, f(x)=10+sin(x) and g(x)=1 is a valid example for two functions where `lim |f(x)/g(x)|` does not exist in `R` (the set of all real values), but `lim sup |f(x)/g(x)|` does. That is what I meant. However, from one example, I would not jump to any conclusions how often these cases occur - which is a question which would only make sense in some context, and even when we know the context, it can be hard to answer.

Comment: Okay, and the last one. Is there any logical reason why `g(x)=1` is called asymptotic upper bound for the function `f(x)=10+sin(x)`? For the functions `f(x)=2x^2+10x` and `g(x)=n^2` there is a logical reason (for me) since `lim f(x)/g(x) (with x->inf)` gives `c`. `c` represents the value we are approaching to (but never reach)  as x goes to infinity. So it's the "real" asymptote. In the case of the functions `f(x)=10+sin(x)` and `g(x)=1` we can calculate `lim sup f(x)/g(x)`, but that's not the asymptote (not the value we constantly approach, because we oscillate, that is go to it and from it).

Comment: @joke: I am under the impression you are overthinking this. What counts for you as a *logical reason*? It is called an asymptotic **upper bound**, not an **asymptote**.  and if you look at the supremum of all values of |f(x)/g(x)| (from some "starting point" x0), the sequence does not oscillate with an increasing x0, it is just the constant value 11. I think you are probably struggling with the "supremum" idea, but when we make things formally correct in mathematics, we have sometimes to leave the ground of simple, intuitive terms.

Comment: This confuses me `and if you look at the supremum of all values of |f(x)/g(x)| (from some "starting point" x0), the sequence does not oscillate with an increasing x0, it is just the constant value 11.`. Supremum is 11 but sequence oscillates between 9 and 11. I mean, we have constant 10 to which values from -1 to +1 (sin(x)) are added which depends on x going to +inf? Right?

Comment: @joke: I was talking about `h(x0)= sup{|(f(x)/g(x))| : x > x0}`. In this case, this function returns 11 for all x0.

Comment: Well, my confusion comes from the fact that I asked why does big O represent asymptotic notation. Then you gave me an amazing answer from which I found a relation between asymptote, upper bound and big O. For example, f(x)=2x^2+10, g(x)=n^2 where the f(x)/g(x) goes towards 2 as x->+inf, 2 represents asymptote of the  f(x)/g(x) and g(x) asymptotic upper bound of the f(x). Everything was clear to me, until the example f(x)=10+sin(x) comes. In this example we don't have any asymptote. So, in general at the end, there need not be any asymptotes. Can we agree about this?

Comment: It looks like there are 2 cases. First where some asymptote exists (example with f(x)=2x^2+10) and second where asymptote does not exist (example with f(x)=10+sin(x)). Thus, using `lim sup` covers the both cases, since when asymptote exists then **lim = lim sup and we (f/g) go towards some value** (so the grow of the function is limited since we go to that value), and in second case it gives a value as **an upper limit that is not exceeded** (so the grow of the function is again limited, not by constantly going to it, but by the way we can't exceed it). I think that's some kind of conclusion?

Answer (score 20):

> What does asymptotic mean in the context of algorithmic analysis?

It means that someone, at some point during the last 130 years, looked at Bachmann-Landau notation and thought "Hey, this looks kinda-sorta like what we use asymptotes in analytic geometry for, so let's call it *asymptotic analysis*.

No more. No less.

In particular, since asymptotes are a concept from analytic geometry, and this is not analytic geometry, there can be no expectation that the term means the same thing.

In analytic geometry, an asymptote can be used as a rough idea of how the graph of a function f(n) behaves as n grows large. Bachmann-Landau notation can be used as a rough idea of how fast a function f(n) grows compared to another functions g(n) as n grows large.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hey Jörg, It seems that you are the only one who really understood my question and what is the source of my misunderstanding. Thanks for that. So, while in mathematics we could represent asymptotes through two things: 1) X grows towards +/- inf 2) based on (1) the function f(x) goes towards some value/line (asymptote). In the analysis of algorithms, there is only (1) from mathematics, while (2) is defined differently. That (2) in this case would represent the way in which the function grows as X increases (nature of growth) in comparison with some standard classes defined through g(x).

Comment: Therefore, there are no real asymptotes as in mathematics, i.e. there is nothing to which the function f(x) (the one we observe) goes. Here, the term "asymptotic" is taken on the basis of point (1), i.e. on the basis that we observe the behavior of the algorithm as X grows towards infinity, but not in the context of approaching some value/line (asymptote in mathematics) but in the context of the nature of growth in comparison with some standard classes defined through g(x) such as n, n^2, logn. Therefore, the upper bound O(n) is not an asymptote. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: This is not bad answer, however, I think the term "asymptotic upper bound" in computer science is stronger connected to asymptotes from analytical geometry than just "it looks somewhat similar".

Answer (score 10):

I think you're overthinking the whole asymptotic "but never reaches" aspect, that's not terribly important. Also, forget about trying to incorporate a bunch of grad-school level math, that just really isn't important here either.

Big O is just to describe how the runtime of a function grows as its input grows to be **Huge™** in size. **Huge™** is a sufficiently technical quantity. We programmers are regularly using the same 'tool' to work with data sets that span several orders of magnitude in size, this is something that is basically unique to this field. The same code might be use to select which choice from a vending machine, as to select one of trillions of records, (aka **Huge™**). In no other field does that sort of thing take place.

So, when are running our algorithm on those datasets several trillions of records in size, all the hardware quirks, constant factors, and other trivia is shaken out and becomes a rounding error compared to those resulting Big O factors. We're never going to approach infinity because we're probably never going to have harddrives the size of the solar system, so we just kinda play fast and loose and deciding when we're big enough.

When we're doing the math to actually compute the complexity of an algorithm, we can compare asymptotic aspects of each contributor to the growth to decide which are important and which are not, which can be some tricky grad-school math. But you may have intuitively realized some of it, in your comment `f(x) = 2x^2 + 4x + 30` it should be plain to recognize that as x gets Huge™ only x^2 is going to matter, and the others are rounding noise. For a simple example we can intuit that plainly, but to formally prove it in a grad-school level class we need to use limits and all the asymptotic math you're fretting about.

But to compare algorithms that have been analyzed, we don't have to think nearly as hard.

Answer (score 1):

Some vocabulary and theorems and notations to reconcile the geometry of asymptotes and asymptotical analysis.

A bit of vocabulary:

- A function g is **an asymptote** of function f at +oo if the absolute difference |f-g| tends towards 0 at +oo.
- A function g is **a linear asymptote** of function f at +oo if g is an asymptote of f and g is a linear function.
- A function g is **an asymptotical upper bound** of function f at +oo if f ≤ g in the neighbourhood of +oo.

A theorem:

- A function f always has at most one linear asymptote at +oo.

A bit more vocabulary:

- If f has a linear asymptote g at +oo, then g is sometimes called **the** asymptote of f at +oo.

And finally a bit of notation:

- f ∈ O(g) means that there exists a constant K > 0 such that K g is an asymptotical upperbound of f.

Comment: Hey Stef, what do you think about Doc Browns answer and the way he explained it?

Comment: @joke I really like it.

Comment: The way he explained it was phenomenal. You have provided additional information and definitions, thanks for that. As far as I understand, g(x) represents the **asymptotic upper bound** of the function f(x), because when we put those two functions in the relation (f(x)/g(x)), g(x) limits the function f(x) in its growth . And in that way, with the growth of x towards inf in the ratio f(x)/g(x), g(x) prevents f(x) from growing but only goes towards some value (for example 2).

Comment: Therefore, g(x) is not an upper bound for f(x) because there are no values of g(x) greater than f(x), for example f(x)=2x^2+10x and g(x) = x^2, for every x, f(x) is greater. Also g(x) is not an asymptote of f(x) because f(x) does not approach g(x). It is something between, **an asymptotic upper bound**. Am I right?

Comment: @joke Yes, everything you said sounds right. I'd be careful though; the term "asymptotic upper bound" is often used somewhat informally without an explicit definition, and depending on context, "g is an asymptotic upperbound of f" might mean either "in the neighbourhood of +oo, g is an upperbound of f" or "there exists a constant K > 0 such that in the neighbourhood of +oo, Kg is an upperbound of f".

Comment: When you say it has a different meaning that is based on the context, you mean in general the term **`asymptotic upper bound`** has a different meaning? But when the context is big O notation, then the asymptotic upper bound refer to this second one (`there exists a constant K > 0 such that in the neighbourhood of +oo, Kg is an upperbound of f`)? That is, f(x)=O(g(x)) as x->inf if there exist some constants c, x0 such that |f(x)| < c|g(x)| for all x > x0. So in this case and this context (context of big O), g(x) is an **asymptotic upper bound** of f(x), and cg(x) is a **upper bound** of f(x)?

Comment: @joke That depends on who is saying it. For some people the "asymptotic' in "asymptotic upperbound" just means "in the neighbourhood of +oo", while for other people the "asymptotic" in "asymptotic upperbound" means both "in the neighbourhood of +oo" and "up to a multiplicative constant". In general, authors tend to not write down their preferred formal definition of "asymptotic upperbound" and you have to guess on context, but it's not too important because they will *also* use precise formal notation in addition to those not-explicitly-precisely-defined words.

Comment: Thank you very much. And the last one (it's a bit off-topic). What do you think about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222489) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222955) that say that big O is not well defined in terms of limits. Should we pay too much attention to it?

Comment: @joke Limits deal with exact values. Big O deals with orders of magnitude. A simple example is the function f(n) = 10 + sin(n). It oscillates between 9 and 11, so you cannot say that it has a limit; but it is bounded above and bounded away from 0, which we can write as ( f(n) = O(1) and 1 = O(f(n)) ) or alternatively f(n) = Theta(1).

Comment: @joke Note that "f = O(g)" is an abuse of notation and it really means "f ∈ O(g)".

Comment: Thanks a lot Stef. I took some time to think about all this, that's why I didn't reply or thank you earlier. Really appreciate your help. You are helping me a lot. Could you perhaps take a look at the comment(s)/text I left below Doc Browns answer and let me know what you think? I tried in my own way to explain and make the connection between the O notation and the asymptotes. I would really appreciate it if you pointed out if I misunderstood something. **Thank you very much in advance.**

Comment: Hey Steph, if you see this message, could you please reply to what I wrote above in Doc Brown's answer (there are additional comments) here, so that we don't bother Doc Brown.

Comment: @joke An added difficulty is that in math we often talk about one function f, for instance saying f(n) = O(g(n)), but in computer science we usually talk about "the complexity as a function of n" but actually the complexity doesn't just depend on n. Take the quicksort algorithm. Sorting an array of length n takes between n log2(n) and n^2 operations, depending on the array. So you can say that the complexity of quicksort is O(n^2), even though we don't really have one function f that maps integer n to the exact time of execution of the algorithm on an input of length n.

Comment: Right, I absolutely understand that. `nlogn` represents the best case, while `n^2` is the worst case, so we take the worst case. However, I think I didn't really understand what you wanted to point out with your comment above (comment inside Doc Brown's answer). Is that what I said through the `10+sin(x)` example or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For Big O, the upper bound is the asymptote.

Big O notation doesn't tell you how long a method will take. It tells you how the shape of the worst case scenario grows as n grows. We expect how long the method typically takes to remain under this limit.

When we first learn about asymptotes in school they are simply straight lines with no curves. That isn't always the case here. These asymptotes can curve.

Big O is only one of [the asymptotic notations](http://web.mit.edu/broder/Public/asymptotics-cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: The point of the asymptote in mathematics, as far as I know mathematics (and I don't know much of it) is that as X increases (decreases), our function approaches the asymptote, but never reaches it. With big O notation, this is not the case. If we have the function f(x) = 2x^2 + 4x + 30, the big O complexity, that is, the upper bound is g(x) = x^2. In what way does f(x) approach g(x) as x increases? I would say that is not the case here.

Comment: Also, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222489) they say that the big O notation is not properly definable in terms of limits (lim). And the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222955) below said in additional that the limits are wrong way of thinking about asymptotic notation and expansions.

Comment: *"For Big O, the upper bound is the asymptote."* - not really. See my answer.

Comment: *"It tells you how the shape of the worst case scenario grows as n grows."* << Well, only if you're talking about the worst case scenario. You can also use big O to discuss the average time of execution, or the time of execution under a particular assumption, or anything else. Also, big O only expresses upper bounds, so the sentence "the time complexity is O(n^3)" would be correct even if the worst-case scenario actually was 10 n^2 log(n) and not n^3. (And this happens often in practice, because identifying and proving a tight upper bound could be much more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers already, but if you look at the [Wikipedia entry for the word "asymptote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote), you find, amongst the modern mathematical definition, this nugget:

> The word asymptote is derived from the Greek [...] which means "not falling together" [...]. The term was introduced by Apollonius of Perga [...] to mean any line that does not intersect the given curve.

The term O(n) means, according to [Wikipedia's page on the O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> f(x) is big O of g(x) if the absolute value of f(x) is at most a positive constant multiple of g(x) for all sufficiently large values of x

Visually, you can think of two curves going to infinity, with the curve y=f(x) not intersecting the curve y=c*g(x) for x greater than some value x0, and c positive. (If you are nitpicking, the definition of O allows for the two curves "joining", i.e. f(x) = c*g(x). But for some interpretation of "intersect" which allows the curves "bumping together" like that (just not passing beyond each other), this would be just fine. If it *really* bothers you, then define g'(x) =  g(x)+1 to "unbump" the curves).

So while I have no idea why the first person using the word "asymptote" in this context actually did so, this seems like a very plausible explanation to me.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a name. Asymptotes in geometry do not have much in common with asymptotic analysis and you will get no insights in trying to find a logical connection between them.

There may be some historical / etymological reason why asymptotes and asymptotic analysis have a partially common name, but afaik those are almost unrelated in modern math. (The only similarity is that both deal with what happens "at infinity".)

To give another example which i find similar: The words "butter" and "butterfly" have very similar names, because people once thought these insects steal butter. But you can gain no insight regarding butter or butterflies when looking for a connection.

Comment: I completely disagree with your first paragraph.

Comment: @Stef why? The only common thing is that both describe behavior at infinity. f(x) = x \in O(e^x) is a true statement, how would you relate that to any geometric asymptote?

Comment: Because it's defeatist. There is definitively a connection, and there is definitively insight to be gained. In fact, if you look at the OP's comments on this page, it looks like the OP did gain a lot of insight by asking this question here.

Comment: Yes, of course you can learn something from every question, so maybe my statement was too absolute. Still, I don't think that investigating this "connection" is very fruitful and I certainly don't think that advising a learner which questions lead to interesting answers and which don't, is defeatist. And it seems to me, that every insight OP gained by asking this question here could also have been gained by asking questions about asymptotic analysis alone.

Comment: See DocBrown's answer for what they have to do with each other. In asymptotic analysis, we try to find a `g(x)` so that `|f(x)/g(x)|` has a horizontal (geometrical) asymptote.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I don't deny that there are some connections, I just don't think that you can learn much from them, especially when learning the concept for the first time. When you actually try to find/imagine an asymptotic bound you almost never look at the quotient f(x)/g(x), even though thats the formal definition. Instead you directly try to bound the function in question. I have also never seen that asymptotic analysis is introduced by falling back to asymptotes anywhere.